# C*-algebra of polynomials?

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Consider its cartesian square $A^2$ and define a multiplication on $A^2$ by the identity
$$
(x_0,x_1)\cdot (y_0,y_1)=(x_0y_0,x_0y_1+x_1y_0),\qquad x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1\in A
$$
This turns $A^2$ into the algebra of "polynomials of one variable of degree 1 with coefficients in $A$": if we denote by $t$ this variable, then each element of $A^2$ can be represented as a polynomial
$$
p(t)=x_0+x_1\cdot t,\qquad x_0,x_1\in A,
$$
and the multiplication in $A^2$ will be the usual multiplication of polynomials (under the agreement that $t^2=0$):
$$
p(t)=x_0+x_1\cdot t,\quad q(t)=y_0+y_1\cdot t
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
p(t)\cdot q(t)=(x_0+x_1\cdot t)\cdot (y_0+y_1\cdot t)=x_0\cdot y_0+(x_0y_1+x_1y_0)\cdot t
$$

> Is it possibe to define a natural C*-norm on $A^2$?

I mean a C*-norm $\|\cdot\|_{A^2}$ such that
$$
\|(x_0,0)\|_{A^2}=\|x_0\|_A,\qquad x_0\in A.
$$

Similarly one can define the algebra of polynomials of $m$ variables of degree $n$ with coefficients in $A$, and I am curious in the same question for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Polynomials" seems like a misleading name; what you're actually doing is trying to adjoin nilpotents.

Anyway, the answer is no, this is already impossible when $A$ is commutative (with no naturality assumption: it is not possible to define any C*-norm on the underlying algebra). The reason is that adjoining nilpotents in the way you want to a commutative C*-algebra gives another commutative C*-algebra, but commutative C*-algebras have no nonzero nilpotent elements by the commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I need a name for such algebras, what do people call them?

Comment: No, I mean a name for the class of such algebras. I thought they can be called "algebras of polynomials of a given degree with coefficients in a C*-algebras". Are you saying that this is inapt?

Comment: I'm saying it's misleading because polynomials of a given degree form a vector space, not an algebra; you've chosen a multiplication so that the variables you're adjoining are nilpotent, but you could choose others.

Comment: If we define a multiplication like I describe, polynomials of given degree form an algebra.

Comment: Yes, but that's a choice you've made that you're hiding with the use of the term "polynomial." I'm not saying your definition isn't meaningful, just that using the term "polynomial" for it is misleading.

Comment: This is strange, I can't find the definition for adjoined elements in an algebra. Is it assumed automatically that the adjoined elements must commute with each other and with the elements of the initial algebra $A$?

Comment: @Sergei: no, of course you can adjoin whatever you want. When I write $A[t]$ and so forth I have in mind primarily the commutative case. If $A$ is noncommutative I don't know what the standard notation is for adjoining a new element with no commutativity requirements.

Comment: One of the most unpleasant things in our work is seeking a proper term... My algebra $A$ is not commutative, but those adjoined elements must commute with each other and with elements of $A$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Any hint on why $t$ in $A[t]$ would have spectrum $\{0\}$? To me, if $A[t]$ denotes the polynomial algebra in $t$ with coefficients in $A$, the spectrum of $t$ should be $\mathbb{C}$. Perhaps $A[t]$ denotes the algebra of entire functions in $t$ with coefficients in $A$. This makes sense too. In this case, which norm is this space equipped with?

Comment: @Jeyrome: whoops, you're right.